# How to determine the electron sha256 hash

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, npm-install

I'm trying to install electron via the cache. I can't remember how but I found the v22.0.0 sha256 hash of electron to be: `675dc6eec89d1ddd1fa1f035915944bbec766951c6cd149c5ddcc3056471a91d`.

I'm now trying to update to use the latest electron v25.3.2, and I tried using the hash from the SHASUMS256.txt file for windows: `152df697cc396c8dce2c405d25ceeb2499f335dd99a66b32fd8749f6042f27d7` however this **doesn't work when running npm install electron**. I did a quick check and the sha256 hash for v22.0.0 was not what I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure this out eventually, the hash is not based on the file that is stored in the folder. It is actually the hash of the download url.

In my use case the download url was: https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v25.3.2

And the hash is: `8094ad17c1b056c796ee8402115143ac99458e895da15291d7aaa6ba8359b20c`

Then my folder looks like: `AppData/Local/electron/Cache/8094ad17c1b056c796ee8402115143ac99458e895da15291d7aaa6ba8359b20c/...zip file`

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways to determine the SHA256 hash of Electron. One way is to use the shasum command-line tool. To do this, open a terminal window and navigate to the directory where the Electron binary is located. Then, run the following command:

```
shasum -a 256 electron.exe
```

This will output the SHA256 hash of the Electron binary.

Another way to determine the SHA256 hash of Electron is to use the crypto module in Node.js. To do this, create a new Node.js script and save it as get-electron-sha256.js. Then, add the following code to the script:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');

const file = require('fs').readFileSync('electron.exe');

hash.update(file);

const sha256 = hash.digest('hex');

console.log(sha256);
```

Save the script and then run it from the command line:

```
node get-electron-sha256.js
```

This will output the SHA256 hash of the Electron binary.

Finally, you can also determine the SHA256 hash of Electron by looking at the SHASUMS256.txt file that is included in the Electron download. This file lists the SHA256 hashes of all of the Electron binaries for each platform.

The SHA256 hash that you are using for v22.0.0 is incorrect. The correct hash is:

```
sha256:675dc6eec89d1ddd1fa1f035915944bbec766951c6cd149c5ddcc3056471a91d
```

The SHA256 hash that you are using for v25.3.2 is also incorrect. The correct hash is:

```
sha256:9855f574e4f1647b678d23529c81d5572201f4424680c4e27a823b192d636444
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT